# Можно как-то вытащить фото с кэша tor на айфоне?

Tags: iphone, кэширование, tor

Как можно вытащить из кэша тора на айфоне изображение ?

Comment: А у него вообще есть кэш?

Comment: Попробуйте поискать по сигнатуре.

Comment: @nick_n_a, у айфонов нет доступной всем приложениям файловой системы. Если это и можно сделать, то либо с компа, либо через сам тор. Ну и поиска там тоже нет...

Comment: Тоже подумал, что всего скорее кэша даже нету у tor'a. Всего скорее при сессии есть может локальный, но стирается сразу после завершение ее.
Но решил спросить все таки, так как может кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой ситуацией.